# widget callback in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

i use android studio to write this code

```
      class CategoryCard extends StatelessWidget {
     var _titlear;
  var _titlefr;
  var _imageUrl;
  var _bgColor;
  VoidCallback _onTap;

  CategoryCard(this._titlear, this._titlefr, this._imageUrl, this._bgColor, this._onTap);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: _onTap,
      child: DecoratedBox(
       ......
}
```

this is state class

```
CategoryCard(
        'طــب  الأسنان',
        'Chirurgiens Dentistes',
        'assets/icons/dental.png',
        kOrangeColor,
              () {
                () => DentisteRoute(this._titlear, this._titlefr, this._imageUrl);
          }),
```

But when I click on the card on the phone, nothing happens and does not go to the requested page

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that `DentisteRoute(this._titlear, this._titlefr, this._imageUrl),` `StatefulWidget` or `StatelessWidget` for example

```
   class DentisteRoute extends StatelessWidget {
      final String _titlear;
      final String _titlefr;
      final String _imageUrl;
    
      const DentisteRoute(this._titlear, this._titlefr, this._imageUrl);
      
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: ...,
        );
      }
    }
```

then you can use this code to navigate to that screen

```
CategoryCard(
        'طــب  الأسنان',
        'Chirurgiens Dentistes',
        'assets/icons/dental.png',
        kOrangeColor,
        () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                 MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                    builder: (_) => DentisteRoute(this._titlear,this._titlefr, this._imageUrl),
                 ),
              ),
 ),
```

Comment: Not Working, same problem

Comment: I have updated my answer. It would be helpful if you post what is DentisteRoute exactly.